# How to stretch items in menu (from right to left) - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fixed menu. When I make a hover on an item, all my 3 items move from right to left. I don't know why. I don't expect the way it moves. All I need is one item stretches (from right to left) when I make a hover on it.

HTML code:

```
<div class="cs-menu">
    <div class="item">one</div>
    <div class="item">two</div>
    <div class="item">three</div
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.cs-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  right:10%;
}

.cs-menu .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f9f397;
  transition: width 1s;
 }

 .cs-menu .item:hover {
   width: 150px;
 }
```

Here is my demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/rq9vudfd/5/

I don't understand how the items move together. I hope you can help me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all elements are placed in top to bottom and left to right in browser window.

When you increase the width of one `.item`, it will result in increase of parent width as well. And as elements are drawn from left to right so all your `.item` elements will be moved to left as well.

**Method 1:** Add `margin: 0 0 0 auto;` to `.item`.

```css
.cs-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  right:10%;
}

.cs-menu .item {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f9f397;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.cs-menu .item:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-menu">
  <div class="item">one</div>
  <div class="item">two</div>
  <div class="item">three</div>
</div>
```

**Method 2:** Add `float: right` and `clear: both` css properties to `.item`.

```css
.cs-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  right:10%;
}

.cs-menu .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f9f397;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.cs-menu .item:hover {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-menu">
  <div class="item">one</div>
  <div class="item">two</div>
  <div class="item">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wa. It works the way that I want. But I don't know why. Could you explain a little bit? By the way, thank you so much.

Comment: @user3089480 I've added explanation and you are welcome -:)

Answer (score 1):

Just use float right. Forked [here](https://jsfiddle.net/haje7fyL/).

```
.cs-menu .item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #f9f397;
  transition: width 1s;
  float: right;
  clear: right; 
}
```

The point is that the div that contains the items changes its width to the most large child. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1ek8rts/) to figure it out. The solution proposed is just a possibility. Just take the children on the right someway.

Comment: Wa. It works the way that I want. But I don't know why. Could you explain a little bit? By the way, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following CSS

```
.cs-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  right:10%;
  **width: 40px;**
}

.cs-menu .item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f9f397;
  transition: width 1s;
  **float:right;**
 }

 .cs-menu .item:hover {
   width: 150px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will blow your mind. **FLEXBOX!!** Two lines of code.

```css
.cs-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /*Or space-around*/
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-menu">
    <div class="item">one</div>
    <div class="item">two</div>
    <div class="item">three</div>
</div>
```